# belongsTo Associations not getting mapped using ActiveModelAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on building an e-commerce site. My models and their associations are as follows-

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  // variables
  name: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  display_price: attr(),
  stock: attr(),
  dates: attr(),

  // associations
  taxons: DS.hasMany('taxon'),
  provider: DS.belongsTo('provider', { async: true }),
  images: DS.hasMany('image', { async: true }),
  variant: hasOne('variant'), // 
})

App.Variant = DS.Model.extend({
  // variables
  isMaster: attr(),
  name: attr(),
  images: attr(),

  // associations
  lineItems: DS.hasMany('lineItem'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
})

App.LineItem = DS.Model.extend({
  // variables
  quantity: attr(),
  price: attr(),
  date: attr(),
  meal_type: attr(),
  total: attr(),
  display_amount: attr(),

  // associations
  variant: DS.belongsTo('variant'),
  cart: DS.belongsTo('cart')
})
```

I am loading all the product variants by sending an ajax request (using ActiveModelAdapter).
Now, for adding the variants in the cart, I have an api end point which accepts variant_id and quantity. This end point responds with the whole Cart containing all the Line Items.
When I add the variants from the variant detail view (by clicking 'add' button), the variant is added successfully and I show the Cart with the response. Now, for increasing the quantity of the added Line Item, I need to find the variant from the LineItem. To do so, I am doing the following-

```
lineItem.get('variant')
```

This does not work. To my understanding, since variant belongsTo LineItem, this should have worked.

**EDIT**
Json response while loading products-

```
products: [
{
  id: 1821,
  name: "Almayass- delight",
  price: "15.0",
  display_price: "$15.00",
  available_on: "2014-06-11T18:30:00.000-05:00",
  permalink: "almayass-delight",
  provider_id: 631,
  taxon_ids: [
    821,
    871,
    591,
    1041
  ],
  stock: 40,
  available: true,
  image_ids: [
    3231
  ],
  variant_id: 1811,
  dates: {
    2014-11-20: [
      1,
      2
    ],
    2014-11-21: [
      2
    ]
  },
  description: "BY VESELKA in EAST VILLAGEOne cheese, one potato, one sauerkraut and one   mushroom pierogi, one meatless stuffed cabbage, kasha with mushroom gravy served with sour cream. Delish."
  }
]
```

Also, when I send POST request to create line Item, I get the whole cart in response. The response is as follows-

```
{
      "line_items": [
      {
        "id":60615,
        "quantity":2,
        "price":"20.0",
        "variant_id":2471,
        "display_amount":"$40.00",
        "total":"40.0",
        "date":"2014-11-24",
        "meal_type":1,
        "product_name":"abc",
        "product_images":[
          {
            "id":2301,
            "attachment_file_name":"HanDynasty_MapoTofuVegetarian_1_U.jpg",
            "attachment_width":400,
            "attachment_height":400,
          },
          {
            "id":2281,
            "attachment_file_name":"Junoon_MurgLababdar_1_U.jpg",
            "attachment_width":1204,
            "attachment_height":587,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id":60614,
        "quantity":1,
        "price":"15.0",
        "variant_id":1811,
        "display_amount":"$15.00",
        "total":"15.0",
        "date":"2014-11-24",
        "meal_type":1,
        "product_name":"Almayass- delight",
        "product_images":[
          {
            "id":3231,
            "attachment_file_name":"Almayass_AlmayassDelight_1_U.jpg",
            "attachment_width":400,
            "attachment_height":400,
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: could you include the json response from your ajax request? also, are you getting an error or is it returning undefined?

Comment: @kaungst Added the JSON response. Please have a look. No errors, no undefined.